# Failed to install lupa

Tags: python, pip, lupa

I have tried to install `Lupa` with `pip` and it failed. When I ran `python -m pip install -u lupa` it returned

```
Collecting lupa


Using cached lupa-1.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lupa
  Running setup.py install for lupa ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\minecraft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MINECR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5czdpgpd\\lupa\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MINECR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2rvafopj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    No local build of LuaJIT2 found in lupa directory
    Checking for installed luajit library using pkg-config
    Did not find luajit using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.


Checking for installed lua5.2 library using pkg-config
Did not find lua5.2 using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Checking for installed lua-5.2 library using pkg-config
Did not find lua-5.2 using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Checking for installed lua library using pkg-config
Did not find lua using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Checking for installed lua5.1 library using pkg-config
Did not find lua5.1 using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Checking for installed lua-5.1 library using pkg-config
Did not find lua-5.1 using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Checking for installed lua library using pkg-config
Did not find lua using pkg-config: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

None of LuaJIT2, Lua 5.1 or Lua 5.2 were found. Please install Lua and its development packages, or put a local build into the lupa main directory.
building without Cython
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.6
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lupa
copying lupa\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lupa
copying lupa\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lupa
running build_ext
building 'lupa._lupa' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.6
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\lupa
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL -IC:\Users\minecraft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\minecraft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tclupa/_lupa.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\lupa/_lupa.obj
_lupa.c
lupa/_lupa.c(458): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lua.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\minecraft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MINECR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5czdpgpd\\lupa\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MINECR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2rvafopj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MINECR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5czdpgpd\lupa\
Command "C:\Users\minecraft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MINECR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5czdpgpd\\lupa\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MINECR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2rvafopj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MINECR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5czdpgpd\lupa\
```

Comment: `No local build of LuaJIT2 found in lupa directory`... You need to install that first

Comment: @cricket_007 OP is on a Windows machine.